# Finding modification date of a file recorded in a CD-R

Tags: winapi, session, file-io, last-modified, cd

I need to find out if a file recorded in a [CD-R](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CD-R) under Windows was modified after its first save. I couldn't find any inspector tools for such a purpose. So I was wondering if there is some kind of Windows API that may be used to extract this information. I found some related questions but answers were too low-level (assembly) and not covering multisession writes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is the place to ask that sort of question.

That said, the best option would be to Right Click > Properties > General Tab. There you should see Created date, Modified date, and Accessed Date. If you are looking for something further than that I'm not aware of any way to see a change log since it's a CD. Also because it is a CD (minus) R you shouldn't be able to write file changes to the cd for changes. That's only a CD (plus) R.

If the file was saved on your computer and you have a regularly scheduled backup, you might be able to find older versions of the file that you can restore to. This is found under the "Previous Versions" tab within Properties.

Hope this helps.